# Class loader resource as stream to 'Null', Spring boot microservice jar BOOT-INF

Tags: java, spring-boot

Built a jar with spring boot, one of class requires reading a text file from the class path. Here is the piece of code ..

```
InputStream fp = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("install/release-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/schema/Create-Index.xml");
```

Issue is, fp is returning 'null', and Null Pointer Exception is thrown on its usage.

Here is the jar content..

```
 **jar tvf target/orchestrationservice.jar | grep install**
     0 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/
     0 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/
     0 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/predecessors/
     0 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/predecessors/release-2.2.0/
     0 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/
   633 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/predecessors/release-2.2.0/orchestration_upgrade_set_version.cql
   910 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/predecessors/release-2.2.0/Upgrade-Index.xml
   706 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/Prod-Index.xml
  1108 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/Create-Index.xml
   465 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/orchestration_3.0_fresh_install_schema.cql
  1356 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/orchestration_3.0_fresh_install_tables.cql
    28 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/orchestration_3.0_fresh_install_tables_data.cql
   651 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/orchestration_3.0_fresh_install_tables_idx.cql
   296 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/orchestration_3.0_set_version.cql
  2135 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/StepExecutionOrder.xml
   128 Fri Feb 10 19:19:06 PST 2017 BOOT-INF/classes/install/UpgradePaths.xml
```

After switching versions of Spring Boot, BOOT-INF/classes/** is introduced. Earlier it was just /classes/**, and resource was loaded fine.

Can you please help me with, how to read a resource with BOOT-INF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

> "install/release-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/schema/Create-Index.xml"

This is what's in your jar-file:

> "BOOT-INF/classes/install/release-3.0.0/schema/Create-Index.xml"

Also, when using Spring, it's more idiomatic to use `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` when getting files from the classpath.

Comment: Class path resource is usually, searched after /classes/*. We need not mention entire path right. ?

Comment: if you explicitly have release-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT, then it won't find release-3.0.0